# how can we sent html content by java gwt mail api

Tags: java, gwt

i peek in many mail api like gmail etc. they send html content by mail api ,almost a form with some widgets. I am also trying to do that but whenever in try this with html content , its giving me error

```
  String to="xyz@gmail.com";//change accordingly


  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
  props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return new PasswordAuthentication("xyz.com","xyz");
   }
  });


  try {
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("hellofacebook180@gmail.com"));
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
   message.setSubject(input);
   message.setContent("<h1>sending html mail check</h1>","text/html" );;


   Transport.send(message);

   System.out.println("message sent successfully");

  } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}

  return "massage sent";
```

please help how can I sent Html content with mail api

Comment: I have a external css in my Html document. is there any way to send my html document witht external css by mail api

Answer (score 0):

Email clients (Gmail, etc.) do not allow external CSS files. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: ok but i have some images which i used in my hhml document . how can i link these images during send mail whereas my internal css in not working..:( please help